# powerapps search sharepoilint list users in dropdown

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-formula

I have a single list that match me application user with Office365 user.
The Sharepoint list is something like this:

ListName= AppUsersList
Fields:
AppUserGuid (Text32)
Username (O365User, only users no multiselect)

Now in my PowerApps I need to search office 365 user and get the UserGuid associated.

I have added a dropdown whith these properties:

DataSource: AppUsersList
isSearchable: true
SelectMultiple: false

The first problem is with the DisplayFields and the SearchField: Powerapps allows me to insert only the
AppUserGuid or the built in fields of any sharepoint list (Title, Path ecc.)

My goal is to select a Username to have his associated AppUserGuid.

I think it is possibile, and even simple but I can't?

Thanks for your help

Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use complex fields as 'DisplayFields' .You can directly use 'Office 365 Users' connection as the datasource for the dropdown

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365users/